# How to return an array that has been sorted against a specific value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Below is my code

```
$gamePrice = 1350;

$arr = array(1233, 4445, 1100, 9008, 900, 1320, 1390, 1320, 1400);


function getClosest($gamePrice, $arr){
            $closestAnswer = null;
            foreach($arr as $guess){
                if($closestAnswer == null || abs($gamePrice - $closestAnswer)>(abs($guess - $gamePrice))){
                    $closestAnswer = $guess;
                }
            }
            return $closestAnswer;
        }

echo getClosest($gamePrice, $arr);
```

So at the moment this just returns the value - 1320 which is the value that is closest to $gamePrice - 1350.

What I would like to happen though is for the function to return an array eg $arr2 which is sorted with the closest answer at the beginning of the array, ie $arr2[0] and the rest of the answers in descending order from this value, that is the next closest answer should be $arr[1] and the furthest answer from the game price should be at the end of the sorted array.

I hope this is clear and someone could help soon.

Thanks.

Comment: can you write the output you expect here?

Comment: Well since @MarkBaker is faster...http://3v4l.org/4vFpp

Comment: @Passerby - Nothing to stop you posting your slightly cleaner version: I've just been tweaking mine to handle equidistant values so lower than the target would be treated as earlier in the sort than the higher (e.g. if one of those 1320s was 1380)

Comment: @MarkBaker Since the question is relatively not difficult I just feel not necessary to post another answer simply because it's "cleaner"...and if you want to somehow maintain the order, I found [a comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php#112994) that may help.

Comment: I delete my answer in favor of Passerby or Mark Baker. Great idea with usort.

Comment: @Calum why are u deleting the answer..dats also right answer in a different way.....

Comment: If you had 1349 and 1351, it would only show one of them in the array. You can use a small random number to solve this problem, but there is still a small chance that the random numbers would be identical. I think usort is a much better option.

Comment: @Calum - As my answer requires PHP >= 5.3.0, and there may still be people running earlier versions of PHP for which your answer would work and mine doesn't, it's still useful to have it here... undelete it

Comment: Ok! Updated answer to fix all the issues with the previous too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$gamePrice = 1350;
$arr = array(1233, 4445, 1100, 9008, 900, 1320, 1390, 1320, 1400);
var_dump(closest($arr, $gamePrice));

function closest($arr, $gamePrice) 
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
    {
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x++)
        {
            // Swap index if difference is less
            if (abs($arr[$i] -  $gamePrice) < abs($arr[$x] -  $gamePrice))
            {
                $var = $arr[$i];
                $arr[$i] = $arr[$x];
                $arr[$x] = $var;
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: Huh, how do you handle with two `1320`s? Wouldn't one of them got overwritten?

Comment: Thanks guys, two great answers, just what I was looking for, have chosen Calum's answer as it supports earlier versions of php although the usort method is great as well

Answer (score 1):

```
$gamePrice = 1350;

$arr = array(1233, 4445, 1100, 9008, 900, 1320, 1390, 1320, 1400);

usort(
    $arr,
    function($a, $b) use ($gamePrice) {
        $r1 = abs($gamePrice - $a);
        $r2 = abs($gamePrice - $b);
        if ($r1 == $r2) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($r1 < $r2) ? -1 : 1;
    }
);

var_dump($arr);
```